# Displaying HTML in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, uiwebview, uitextview

How to open url in textview iphone??

Is it possible to show data with `links`,`photos` and all `html entities`???

Comment: I don't see any magic.

Comment: Jain: why don't you use [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @BoltClock Muggles just don't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with `UITextView` control. Use `UIWebView` or make your own custom control.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UIWebView to load a static contain from files; html, photo, css, javascript.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

then just add "index.html" as normal HTML standard to your project.

```
<html>
   <head><title>Hello</title></head>
   <body>
      <img src="icon.png"/>
      <p>Test</p>
   </body>
</html>
```