# Call Javascript function of webpage in cocoa webview

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, webview

First, I'm a complete newbie at objective-c and cocoa. I've found resources related to this, but none showing what I want, and I can't seem to get the others to work for me. What I need is a really dumbed-down example with a window containing a button and a webview that has an HTML page with a javascript function that takes one parameter (a string or something), and spits it out via `document.write`. (I know javascript).

Then when you click the button outside of the webview, it will call the javascript function, and the webview will say something, from the `document.write` call. If someone could perhaps put together a quick example like this, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a) to call javascript in your web view.

```
[ webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"myJavascriptFunction()" ];
```

This is not as complete an example as you have asked for but a complete application example is somewhat beyond what is appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: My problem is where do I specify `webView`? I can add a webview in interface builder, but how do I connect it with that code?

Comment: The most common way is to use IBOutlets (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html). If this is new to you I think you would benefit from working through one of the many Cocoa tutorial books like Cocoa Programming for Mac OSX http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Programming-Mac-OS-3rd/dp/0321503619

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to call a Javascript function, this is the way to do it:

```
WebScriptObject *script = [_webView windowScriptObject];
[script callWebScriptMethod:@"jsFunctionWithText" withArguments:@[@"Some text"]];
```

In your HTML page you'll need the following:

```
<script>
function jsFunctionWithText(text)
{
    document.write(text);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the previous solutions worked for me. However, I found [this method in the Apple Developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html) which did allow me to execute JS code in my webView successfully.

Here is an example that worked for me in XCode 4.6.1 (OS X 10.8.3):

`[[webView windowScriptObject] evaluateWebScript:@"document.write('derp')"];`

Answer (score 2):

To get the WebView working see this awesome tutorial by Lost Decade Games:

[How to embed HTML5 into a native Mac OSX app](http://blog.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-embed-html5-into-a-native-mac-osx-app).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to see my answer on this question - [Displaying HTML in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777992/displaying-html-in-iphone-app)

then you can use javascript as just normal html standard by add them to your XCode project's file.